# "403 Forbidden" when loading CSS from blog.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, blog, 403-forbidden

### Here is the **ugly display** in my browser when accessing [blog.stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)

> [image: screen shot]

---

### Here's the Chrome Developer Windows output

> [image: Developer Window output]

---

### And here's the screenshot where I visit the CSS URL

> [image: CSS URL shows 403]

---

### wget output

```
$ wget https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/themes/se-company/style.css
converted 'https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/themes/se-company/style.css' (US-ASCII) -> 'https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/themes/se-company/style.css' (UTF-8)
--2015-03-18 12:34:49--  https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/themes/se-company/style.css

Resolving blog.stackoverflow.com (blog.stackoverflow.com)... 104.16.24.251, 104.16.25.251
Connecting to blog.stackoverflow.com (blog.stackoverflow.com)|104.16.24.251|:80... connected.

HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2015-03-18 12:34:49 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

---

### Curl Output

```
curl -o /dev/null -v blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/themes/se-company/style.css
* Adding handle: conn: 0x80134f008
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x80134f008) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to blog.stackoverflow.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 104.16.24.251...
* Connected to blog.stackoverflow.com (104.16.24.251) port 80 (#0)
> GET /wp-content/themes/se-company/style.css HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.31.0
> Host: blog.stackoverflow.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Date: Wed, 18 Mar 2015 06:16:56 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=dc6b1661196b68bb9218bd8bbf831bf4a1426659415; expires=Thu, 17-Mar-16 06:16:55 GMT; path=/; domain=.stackoverflow.com; HttpOnly
< CF-Cache-Status: REVALIDATED
< Set-Cookie: prov=50f26b49-a861-4312-86d3-f5b3c3de42cf; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2048 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.stackoverflow.com; HttpOnly
* Server cloudflare-nginx is not blacklisted
< Server: cloudflare-nginx
< CF-RAY: 1c8ecfc327c5081d-SIN
<
{ [data not shown]
100   328    0   328    0     0    334      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   334
* Connection #0 to host blog.stackoverflow.com left intact
```

---

I also checked the status code of this URL https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/themes/se-company/style.css from several online checkers

- http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php → 403 Forbidden
- http://web-sniffer.net/ → 200 OK
- https://monitorbacklinks.com/seo-tools/http-header-status-check → 200 OK
- http://httpstatus.io/ → 200 OK

*Yay, looks like one of URL checkers can reproduce my problem here.*

Additional info: **My IP Address is 167.205.22.xx**. It's IP address of Squid load balancer.

---

**Update:**

After getting help from [Jason Harvey](http://blog.serverfault.com/2015/02/26/welcome-jason-harvey-server-fault-valued-associate-0000009/) aka [alienth](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282398/alienth) (*still wondering where is his diamond name*), the page was load perfectly. However, [recaptcha.css URL](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-recaptcha/recaptcha.css) still gives [403 Forbidden status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrq3I.png). [This online checker](http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php) also confirmed my case.

Comment: I know the cause here, but it should've been fixed. Can you please give me the output from the following command?

curl -o /dev/null -v http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/themes/se-company/style.css

Comment: @alienth See my edit above

Comment: Thanks! I've manually fixed the issue for now, but unfortunately I need to do further hunting on the root cause (which I thought had been addressed yesterday).


Approximately how long have you been seeing this consistently? Also, do you recall when it last worked?

Comment: I visited that site last week ago and it was worked :). Then today when I visit it again, I  got this issue :(. Based on my squid log, today I visited that site at **Wed Mar 18 12:33:16.754 +0700**

Comment: yay, the good looking page of blog.stackoverflow.com is come back :))

Comment: Anyway, after you get the root cause please post it in the answer section below. Then I can accept it and this question won't float in [unanswered question pool](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered) :)

Comment: sidenote: @alienth Can you ask a dev to add your diamond on this site?

Comment: @rene actually employees should be able to add moderator-only tags even without diamond. Seen it more than once in the past. Diamond is just for show. ;-)

Comment: @alienth, this problem still persist in rechaptca.css URL: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-recaptcha/recaptcha.css . See update above

Comment: @masegaloeh Issue should be *permanently* resolved now. Will include details in the answer box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here's what was happening:

For an as of yet undiscovered reason, Apache would occasionally 403 static assets on our blog. When it does this it sends a `Last-Modified` header. CloudFlare sees this 403 and deems it cachable. When CloudFlare goes to fetch the asset again, they reach out to the origin with an `If-Modified-Since` request for the asset, which will always return a `304 Not Modified` response, since our static assets rarely change. This resulted in any 403 sticking around permanently.

To address this improper sticky 403 behaviour I've altered our reverse proxy to send a `cache-control: no-cache` to our 403 responses from the blog.

Comment: No diamond @alienth ?

Comment: Not as of yet. I have yet to swear fealty to Bahamut.. err.. get some of my SE stuff established. All in due time. Yes, *all* in due time.

Comment: Cool :) Congrats on the job then! (*Google dictionary: vast fish* :p)

Comment: Great, thanks for explanation.  To all mods please retag it with [status-completed] :)